# Sufficient conditions for polynomial reducibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Are there any nice conditions under which the polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F_p}$ is reducible (completely reducible)?

Is there a way to explain that such a condition does not exist? (which I believe is true)

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by "nice". Any thoughts?

Comment: That can be actually checked for some class of polynomials.

Comment: There are algorithms which work for all polynomials, but they are not so suitable for hand use. Is that "nice" or not?

Comment: I am looking for condition, not algorithm. For example, I don't know how to check reducibility in terms of coefficients for the polynomial of fourth degree (when coefficients are not concrete, just some parameters)

Comment: How do you check for polynomials of degree two and three? My guess would be that for degree two you would use the condition that the discriminant is a square. This suggest some definition of nice namely that some polynomial expression in the coefficients must be a pure power. Now if you request that kind of niceness I can imagine that with some work you can show it impossible by showing that it would imply general polynomials being solvable by radicals. However for broader definitions of niceness it seems a lot harder to show impossibility.

Answer (score 1):

Over $\mathbb{Q}$ you are asking whether the polynomial factors into linear factors (I think). Since there are [bounds](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno//CS874/Lectures/ResultantGcd.html/node5.html) for the roots (or in general, coefficients of factors) in terms of the coefficients. So, if you combine this with [Gauss' lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29) there are only finitely many cases to check (for low degree polynomials, not so many, though I would not want to do this by hand).

Answer (score 0):

Over $\mathbb{Q}$. If a polynomial $f(x)$ has a root $ a \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $f(x)$ is  reducible.  If $a$ is a comlex root of $f(x)$ and $a+\overline{a}, a \cdot \overline{a} \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $f(x)$ is reducible  over $\mathbb{Q}$